# Why do I get infinite requests using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I am trying to create a custom hook function to do data request, but when I call it after creating the hook, the result of infinite request occurs, how can I solve it

**this is request hook**

```
export const useRequest = (resource, params) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetcher = (params) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const query = {
      sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
      range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
      filter: JSON.stringify(params?.filter ? params.filter : ""),
    };

    http.get(`${resource}?${stringify(query)}`).then((data) => {
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher(params);
  }, [params]);

  return {
    data,
    loading,
  };
};
```

where i call the hook

```
import { useRequest } from "./hooks/useRequest";

function App() {
  const params = {
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
    sort: { field: "updatedAt", order: "DESC" },
  };
  const { data, loading } = useRequest("/posts", params);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="text-white"></div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You don't need useEffect in the first place, you can just call `fetcher(params);` in `useRequest` directly.

Comment: thanks，here is a solution, but I'm trying to figure out why useEffect dependency parameter is changing, why does it change

Comment: Because you are creating a new `params` object every time App renders. React will compare the previous reference to `params` with the new one and think that it has updating. So it will run your effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here:

```
  // Create a new object with a new reference every time App renders
  // and send it into useRequest
  const params = {
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
    sort: { field: "updatedAt", order: "DESC" },
  };
  const { data, loading } = useRequest("/posts", params);
```

```
  // Every time params reference updates, do a fetch
  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher(params);
  }, [params]);
```

The best way to remedy is to never update the reference of `params`, unless its config changes.

```
const params = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
    sort: { field: "updatedAt", order: "DESC" },
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: But I don't just want to request when the page is initialized

Comment: This does the same thing as your code, but doesn't have an infinite loop. You could also return the fetch function from the hook so the caller can fetch whenever it wants `fetch: () => fetcher(params)`

Answer (score 0):

i got anthor solution, use SWR

```
export const useGetList = (resource, params) => {
  const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
  const { field, order } = params.sort;
  const query = {
    sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
    range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
    filter: JSON.stringify(params?.filter ? params.filter : ""),
  };

  const fetcher = (data) => http.get(data).then((res) => res);

  const { data, error } = useSWR(`${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, fetcher);

  return {
    data,
    error,
  };
};

// use
const params = {
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
    sort: { field: "updatedAt", order: "DESC" },
    filter: {},
  };

const { data, error } = useGetList("/posts", params);
```

Comment: a couple notes, (1) `.then((res) => res)` does exactly nothing, so you can safely remove it (2) you shouldn't construct URLs manually using `JSON.stringify`. You should either use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) or since you tagged this with `axios`, you can pass [params](https://axios-http.com/docs/example) to the url using `axios.get(myURL, { params: ... })`.